# UICollectionView stick to a cell even if it's content offset may change

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

This is a hard one, I hope I can explain it properly.

All right, so the thing is that I have a **UICollectionView** where the **height of the cell is dynamically changing** using `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` which guides into the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath()` method of UICollectionVieFlowLayout.

This works perfectly. There is new content, it resizes, moves the other cells according to it, etc. Now, my collection view's content size is probably pretty big, that means when I'm stopping at cell number, say, 23, and cell number 15 is not even displayed but is changing it's size, it is going to make my cell number 23 move up or down. Can I kind of throw an "anchor" to where I currently am? Here's the code that's resizing the cell, triggered by Firebase:

```
            cell.resizeToText(text: text!)

            let size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: cell.mainView.frame.height + (cell.mainView.frame.origin.y*2.5))
            let invalidationIndex = indexPath.row + 1
            self.invalidationSizeDictionary[invalidationIndex] = size

            let context = UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext()
            context.invalidateItems(at: [indexPath])

            self.feedCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

**Question:** is there a possibility to stay at my current offset position in the collectionView?

Comment: Have you tried using `.reloadData()` instead?

Comment: @DonMag sure, the problem is that I'm calling the code above from within the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, that means that it's going to become an infinite loop and will crash...

Comment: hmmm... how is `cellForItemAtIndexPath` being called for a cell that is not currently displayed?

Comment: It's because there's a Firebase observer that is observing a string in the database. If it changes, the cell should first resize and then invalidate it's layout... That means it is practically always active.

Comment: Can the string update actually change the *layout* of the cells? Or just the y-position and therefore the relative y-offset? i.e. Can it start with, say, 8 rows of 3 cells each, and change so the first row fits only two cells, forcing the 24th cell to wrap onto a 9th row?

Comment: Yeah, it changes the layout accessing the collectionViewLayour property.

Comment: Are you using Flow Layout or a  custom Layout class?